# Inline links in Java Mail not working in mail clients

Tags: java, html, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to add inline links(*# links to inline tables within the HTML body*) by which I can navigate within my email.
I'm using `javax.mail` APIs with the `text/html`.
The problem is that the links don't work when they opened within the email clients such as outlook.
If the mail is opened in the browser (from the *'view in browser option'* in email client) then the links just work fine.

Please assist in resolving this problem (how can I have working inline links within the mail clients).
Below is the class I'm using to send the mail.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import com.afl.crawler.exceptions.CrawlerException;

public class EmailTestClass {

    private static StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CrawlerException {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        List<LocalDate> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            dateList.add(today.minusDays(i));
        }

        configureAndSendMail(dateList);
    }

    private static void configureAndSendMail(List<LocalDate> dateList) throws CrawlerException {

        try {

            Properties smtpProps = new Properties();
            smtpProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            smtpProps.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            smtpProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            smtpProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("me@gmail.com", "myP@ssword");
                }
            };

            Session session = Session.getInstance(smtpProps, auth);
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            InternetAddress[] toAddrs = { new InternetAddress("someone@example.com") };

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("me@gmail.com", "Test Account"));
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddrs);
            msg.setSubject("Test EMail Links");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setContent(getMailContent(dateList), "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Transport.send(msg);

        } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new CrawlerException("Failed to process Email", ex);
        }
    }

    private static Object getMailContent(List<LocalDate> dateList) {

        message.append("<html><head></head><body bgcolor=\"#E1E1E1\" leftmargin=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" topmargin=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" offset=\"0\"><center>");

//      Prepare the Navigation links
        message.append("<div style=\"width: 200px;\"><h2>Navigation Links:</h2><ul>");
        dateList.forEach(date -> {
            message.append("<li><a href=\"#")
            .append(date.toEpochDay())
            .append("\" target=\"_self\">")
            .append(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy")))
            .append("</a></li>");
        });
        message.append("</ul></div>");

//      Prepare the data Tables 
        builddataTables(dateList);

        message.append("</center></body></html>");

        return message.toString();
    }

    private static void builddataTables(List<LocalDate> dateList) {

        dateList.forEach(date -> {
            message.append("<table ")
            .append("id=\"")
            .append(date.toEpochDay())
            .append("\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"width:500px;background-color: #cedbf3;border: 1px solid rgba(19, 14, 14, 0.56);padding:15px;\"><tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"background-color: #5ab4ff;color:#ffffff;line-height:100%;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:center;\">")
            .append(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("cccc, dd MMMM yyyy")))
            .append("</td></tr><tr><td style=\"width:30%;\">Key Dat1</td><td style=\"width:70%;\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac mi eu lorem sagittis lacinia vel ac metus</td></tr><tr><td>Key Data2</td><td>Cras lobortis consectetur mi a porttitor. Vestibulum blandit urna et elit sollicitudin</td></tr></table>");
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You're using relative links, you should use absolute links.

Comment: How do I add absolute links to dynamically created elements?

Comment: I've deleted my answer that wasn't relevant to OP's question (I thought the links were supposed to point to a webapp), however I did provide a relevant link that I'll reproduce here : http://blog.mailermailer.com/tips-resources/anchor-tags-html-emails . This article mentions using `<a name="...">` tags as anchors. Note that I've found [another article](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/11/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/) that mentioned that `id` based anchors should work on some web clients.

Comment: Pete, I won't be posting another answer since I don't plan to test the information provided in these articles, but since you've done so you could add an answer and accept it for future reference :)

Comment: @Aaron done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the links pointed by Aaron, I enclosed the detail table within a named anchor tag.
It has been tested on **Gmail** and **Outlook 2016** clients and is working as expected.
Now the `builddataTables` method implementation is as follows.

```
private static void builddataTables(List<LocalDate> dateList) {
    dateList.forEach(date -> {
        message.append("<a name=\"")
        .append(date.toEpochDay())
        .append("\" id=\"")
        .append(date.toEpochDay())
        .append("\"><table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"width:500px;background-color: #cedbf3;border: 1px solid rgba(19, 14, 14, 0.56);padding:15px;\"><tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"background-color: #5ab4ff;color:#ffffff;line-height:100%;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:center;\">")
        .append(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("cccc, dd MMMM yyyy")))
        .append("</td></tr><tr><td style=\"width:30%;\">Key Dat1</td><td style=\"width:70%;\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac mi eu lorem sagittis lacinia vel ac metus</td></tr><tr><td>Key Data2</td><td>Cras lobortis consectetur mi a porttitor. Vestibulum blandit urna et elit sollicitudin</td></tr></table></a>");
    });
}
```